# how to use GET in django?

Tags: python, django

i am newbie in django. i want to display content of "music and concerts" when url is something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/details/music and concerts`

for that i have tried following in my

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^details/(?P<event_cat>\w{0,50})/$', 'onthemove.views.category'),
)
```

my template index.html is

```
 <div class="cat">
{% if latestevents.count > 0 %}
{% for category in latestevents %}
            <a href="/details/{{ category.cat }}/">
                <div id="per_cat">
                <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/images/music.jpg" />
<span>{{category.cat}}</span>


            </div></a>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<span>none to show</span>
{% endif %}
```

where latestevents is passing from views.py as:

```
def searchget(request):
latestevents = events.objects.all().order_by('id')[:1]
return render_to_response('views/search.html',{'latestevents':latestevents})
```

but this showing error that:

```
The current URL, details/Music and Concerts/, didn't match any of these.
```

is their any mistake ?

Comment: You sure about your regex `r'^details/(?P<event_cat>\w{0,50})/$'`

Comment: maybe You can show us "onthemove.views.category"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` only matches alphanumeric characters, so won't match the whitespace. Perhaps you could use `r'^details/(?P<event_cat>.{0,50})/$'`, but that's still a bit strange: why limit it to 50 characters?

Comment: No criticism of your answer Daniel, as it does indeed work, but I feel the OP is missing the point that spaces in the querystring parameters are going to get converted to `%20`

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to have spaces in your URLs. Instead, try a more human-readable format like "word-word", which would be this pattern:

```
url(r'^details/(?P<event_cat>[-\w]+)/$', 'onthemove.views.category'),
```

This would match: /details/music-and-concerts/

Comment: but in my database there is spaces between music and concerts , it searches for music and concerts from database and then display result. so is there any way so that it would happen ?

Comment: I would recommend adding a `SlugField` for your model to use as a value to pass through the querystring to identify the category.